# Is it necessary to renew a tenancy agreement which states: "Expire on (but continuing thereafter by virtue of statute..)"

Tags: united-kingdom

I have been living in UK for 10 years, lived in 5 different places. Only one of my previous landlords used to renew the contract every year. By renewing I mean signing a new contract and new dates but NO changes.

Is it necessary to do that? when there is no changes in the circumstances or the line above validates the contract even after the expiry date?

Comment: Which statute and what does it say? It seems the lease is actually quite clear on what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a typical private sector tenancy, then it would initially be a fixed-term one year'assured shorthold tenancy' a type of assured tenancy. The [Housing Act 1988 says](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/50/section/5):

> If an assured tenancy which is a fixed term tenancy comes to an end
>   otherwise than by virtue of—
>
> (a) an order of the court of the kind mentioned in subsection
>      (1)(a)
>   or (b) or any other order of the court, or
>
> (b) a surrender or other action on the part of the tenant,
>
> then, subject to section 7 and Chapter II below, the tenant shall be
>   entitled to remain in possession of the dwelling-house let under that
>   tenancy and, subject to subsection (4) below, his right to possession
>   shall depend upon a periodic tenancy arising by virtue of this
>   section.

So if the tenancy was not renewed then it would be replaced with a periodic tenancy. This has different rules to the fixed-term tenancy. Whether renewing the tenancy is necessary or not depends on whether either party strongly prefers the fixed-term tenancy to the periodic.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I have googled the difference between periodic tenancy and fixed-term tenancy. Now I know why my previous landlord insisted on renewing because it went to periodic tenancy he would been able to kick me out.